# Jquery Autocomplete and Auto Suggest

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete, autofill

How do you stop the auto suggest feature from dropping down suggestions while using jquery autocomplete.  The auto suggest is dropping down over the autocomplete selections.  Its terribly annoying. I've tried z-index.  Nothing seems to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers support the autocomplete attribute on html input elements.

```
<input name="textBoxWithoutAutoComplete" autocomplete="off" value="This textbox won't have autocomplete" />
```

more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(v=vs.85).aspx